# SHKActivityIndicator in Sharekit not showing up when shareDelegate is set

Tags: objective-c, facebook, twitter, sharekit

in my app I have customized the sharekit, sending an image to twitter/facebook via pushing my own buttons. for that I needed to created an instance of SHKShaerer and set its Delegate to my Class:

```
self.theSharer = [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
self.theSharer.shareDelegate = self;
```

for this to work properly I also needed to import the Sharer-Class

```
#import "SHKSharer.h"
```

implement the 'SHKSharerDelegate'-Protokoll, added the SHKSharer-instancevariable to the interface, set it to

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) SHKSharer* theSharer;
```

and synthesize it in the .m-file.

then I added the protokoll-methods

```
- (void)sharerStartedSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer{}
- (void)sharerFinishedSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer{}
- (void)sharer:(SHKSharer *)sharer failedWithError:(NSError *)error shouldRelogin:(BOOL)shouldRelogin{}
- (void)sharerCancelledSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer{}
```

and startet to use them.

unfort. since then the SHKActivityIndicator-Messages which told the user what happens nor the error-messages were seen again.

why did that happen and how could I get them back?
thnx!

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the authentification process it is showing the indicator-message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could win if you could read...

I found out that in SHKSharer.m is told that

```
// These are used if you do not provide your own custom UI and delegate
- (void)sharerStartedSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer
{
    if (!quiet)
        [[SHKActivityIndicator currentIndicator] displayActivity:SHKLocalizedString(@"Saving to %@", [[self class] sharerTitle])];
}
...
```

so I need to call these in my own Protokol-Methodas!